# Creating a form based on flight intentory

Tags: typescript, angular-2+

I have an Angular 5 project with a method named `createForm`. It will basically create just a form. However, the form created changes depends on the flight inventory code. If flight inventory code id TAG_ON I will create a form omitting `messagePrefixSMSValidator` and also form control named message to empty.

```
createForm() {

    this.formGroup = this.fb.group(
      {
        defaultTemplate: [this.defaultInitialValue],
        language: [null, Validators.required],
        message: [ this.messagePrefix ? this.messagePrefix:'', [Validators.required]],
        longUrl: ['']
      },
      {
        validator: [
                    hasUrlTagValidator(TemplatesService.urlTag), 
                    messagePrefixSMSValidator(this.messagePrefix? this.messagePrefix: null, 'message')
                  ]
      }
    );

   if(this.flight.inventory.code === FlightInventoryCode.TAG_ON) {

    this.formGroup =  this.fb.group(
      {
        defaultTemplate: [this.defaultInitialValue],
        language: [null, Validators.required],
        message: [ '', [Validators.required]],
        longUrl: ['']
      },
      {
        validator: [
                    hasUrlTagValidator(TemplatesService.urlTag), 
                  ]
      }
    );
   }

  }
```

Is there a way to rewrite my code so that it looks simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Suggested changes](https://codepen.io/a-morn/pen/dxzbBb?editors=0010#0)

- Formatting. Typically you want to use TSLint, and possible also Prettier. I've ran your code through Prettier with the standard configuration. (Note that the point is *consistency* and *readability*. It doesn't matter if you want to use `'` or `"`, tabs or spaces, etc)
- `this.messagePrefix ? this.messagePrefix : ""` can be simplified as `this.messagePrefix || ""`
- Looking at your code, it looks like we want to assign different values to `message` and `validator` depending on the values of `this.flight.inventory.code`. So lets keep everything else the same rather than having separate code paths. *If* we were to keep the current structure, then we should at least put the first assignment to `this.formGroup` in an else block, so we don't assign it twice.

Comment: i didnt understand the last point . could you clarify more ,

Comment: I think the best way to understand it is to compare the codepen I linked to your original code. Hopefully you can see the gain in readability and terseness. It's much more clear that `message` and `validator` (but nothing else) depends on `this.flight.inventory.code` in the codepen version.

Comment: thank you so much .. i saw it in codepen ...brilliant

Comment: Great! Feel free to up vote or accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: done . iforgot to voteup  .thank u